# Проблема с роутингом Class 'Controller' not found in

Tags: php, mvc

Пытаюсь передать значения формы через пост в контроллер, но выходит такая ошибка.

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Controller' not found in C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\controllers\ContractsController.php:7 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\OpenServer\domains\localhost\controllers\ContractsController.php on line 7

**ContractsController**

```
    <?php


class ContractsController extends Controller {

private $pageTpl = "/views/cabinet/contracts.tpl.php";


public function __construct()
{
    $this->model = new ContractsModel();
   
    $this->view = new View();
} ....
```

**Форма**

```
<form action="../../controllers/ContractsController.php" class="auth-form" method="POST">
```

**Роутинг**

```
        <?php
    
    /**
     * Класс маршрутизации
     **
     */
    class Routing {
    
        public static function buildRoute() {
    
            /*Контроллер и action по умолчанию*/
            $controllerName = "IndexController";
            $modelName = "IndexModel";
        $action = "index";

        $route = explode("/", parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH));
        

        $i = count($route)-1;


        while($i>0) {
            if($route[$i] != '') {
                if(is_file(CONTROLLER_PATH. ucfirst($route[$i]). "Controller.php")) {
                    $controllerName = ucfirst($route[$i]). "Controller";
                    $modelName = ucfirst($route[$i]). "Model";
                    break;
                } else {
                    $action = $route[$i];
                }
            }
            $i--;
        }


        require_once CONTROLLER_PATH . $controllerName . ".php"; //IndexController.php
        require_once MODEL_PATH . $modelName . ".php"; //IndexModel.php     

        $controller = new $controllerName();
        $controller->$action(); // $controller->index();


    }

    public function errorPage() {

    }


}
```

Мне кажется, что с роутингом что-то не так

Controller

```
 <?php

class Controller {

    public $model;
    public $view;
    protected $pageData = array();

    public function __construct() {
        $this->view = new View();
        $this->model = new Model();
    }   

}
```

Comment: Что конкретно еще добавить? :( 
Добавил просто контроллер.

Comment: Судя по трассировке ошибки у вас автозагрузка файла класса контроллера не срабатывает. То есть по идее сначала должен загрузиться файл класса контроллера, а потом вызываться один из его методов (по крайней мере в большинстве фрэймворков так. Я по коду не могу определить тот, что вы используете).

Comment: @e_v_medvedev, это самописное MVC приложение D:

Comment: Тогда разберитесь с автозагрузкой файлов. Реализуется это этой функцией https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.spl-autoload-register.php . Это конечно если у вас для сборки проекта не используется composer . Для composer другой немного алгоритм действий.